# Primefaces Serenity theme Submenu stops functioning after update on parent element

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

When loading the page the PrimeFaces Premium theme Serenity "p:submenu" works correctly, however, after performing an update on the "p:outputPanel" where it is "parent element", simply stops working, the submenu don't expand and collapse.

"Expanding and collapsing" only works again if you refresh the page.

Menu:

```
<p:outputPanel id="layout-sidebar" layout="block">
    <h:form id="menuform">
        <pm:menu>
            <p:menuitem id="dashboard"/>
            <p:submenu id="sss" label="sss" icon="sss">
                <p:menuitem value="ttt" icon="ttt"/>
                <p:menuitem value="uuu" icon="uuu"/>
                <p:menuitem value="vvv" icon="vvv"/>
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu id="www" label="www" icon="www">
                <p:menuitem value="xxx" icon="xxx"/>
                <p:menuitem value="yyy" icon="yyy"/>
                <p:menuitem value="zzz" icon="zzz"/>
            </p:submenu>
        </pm:menu>
    </h:form>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Button that performs update:

```
<p:commandLink title="xxx" actionListener="#{xxx.yyy}" update="layout-sidebar"></p:commandLink>
```

JSF 2.3 | Primefaces 6.2 | PrimeFaces Serenity Theme

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please add what PrimeFaces version, JSF version, Server you are using to the details.

Comment: Also is "pm" menu a custom menu or a PrimeFaces custom theme menu?

Comment: JSF 2.3, Primefaces 6.2, "pm:menu" is the same as "p", pm is the one used in premium templates.

Comment: what about that "pm:menu" is that a custom menu?

Comment: "pm:menu" is the menu used in the primefaces premium template "Serenity".

Comment: OK that is what I thought.  I think the bug could be related to Serenity.  Did you try with a non-Serenity menu?   If it is Serenity related you should report it here:  https://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=73  I see that you have.

Comment: I just checked, if you use the default menu of Primefaces "p: menubar" the problem does not exist, it works 100%, so the bug / problem is in the custom menu of the Serenity "pm: menu" template.

Comment: thanks for posting that back.  I had a feeling it was Serenity related.  Hopefuly the PF will fix since its a premium theme.

Comment: I hope so, the difficult thing is that it takes too long to respond and correct. Thanks